# Pointing the input cursor to the end of default text while tabbing through fields?

Tags: angular

I have used tab index in the HTML to tab from one field to another .

Here in the below image it can be seen i am tabbing from Revise to Link .

[image]

But when i press tab , the default text present in the Link field gets completely selected . Like this .

[image]

Is there any way i can point the cursor just at the end of the default text , i.e after = ?

Can anyone please help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is any fixed solution. But I came up with a workaround:

```js
document.getElementById("second").onfocus = () => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  const val = document.getElementById("second").value;
  document.getElementById("second").value = '';
  document.getElementById("second").value = val;
 });
};
```

```html
<label>first:</label><input id="first" type="text">
<br>
<label>second:</label><input id="second" value="some value" type="text">
<br>
```